# SQL Server comparing a column in 2 tables and updating another column in the second table

Tags: sql-server, validation, sql-update

I have 2 tables with columns like this:

Table 1

```
company_name | company_id | update_dt | update_user
```

Table 2

```
company_name | company_id | location | validation_sw | update_dt | update_user
```

I have to compare the records of company_id column in both tables and for all the records in `Table-2` that have matching `company_ids` in `Table-1`, I have to update the corresponding `validation_sw` in `Table 2` to 'Y' and for all the other records in `Table-2` I have to update the `validation_sw` to 'N'. Also, I have to consider only distinct `company_id` columns in `Table-2` since each `company_id` is mapped to different `location` columns.

I created the following query (without consideration of distinct `company_id` in `Table-2` and still it's not working right as it is updating all the records to either 'Y' or 'N' but not just the matching records to 'Y' and others to 'N')

Query:

```
UPDATE Table-2 
 SET validation_sw =  CASE WHEN validation_sw in ( 
     SELECT validation_sw 
     FROM Table-2 tb2 
     INNER JOIN Table-1 tb1 
       ON tb1.company_id = tb2.company_id 
 ) THEN 'Y' 
 ELSE 'N' 
 END;
```

Please help me with modifying the query to update `validation_sw` to 'Y' only for the matching `company_id` records and 'N' for other records considering only distinct `company_id` column records in `Table-2`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
CASE WHEN validation_sw in ( 
     SELECT validation_sw
...
```

You should be using `Company_id` in place of `validation_sw`:

```
CASE WHEN company_id in ( 
     SELECT company_id
...
```

Comment: Thanks much, it's working and would you also please help me in selecting only distinct company_id records from table-2. Btw I did up vote the answer and it will be added as soon as I get 15 score in my reputation as am still new here

Comment: Your question is about how to do an UPDATE.   How does selecting distinct records factor into this update?  Or if you are asking a separate question, please create a new question on the site.

Comment: I mentioned that in the description of question that i have to consider only distinct company_ids in Table-2. Since am new here, do I have to create a new question for a 2 part question? If so, i can create one

Comment: I don't see how using distinct id's will affect your results, can you give an example?